# IntelliJ Annotation Wraping

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

This is a code style issue specific to IntelliJ

Currently annotations display like this:

```
@SomeCustomAnnotation({
        "PARAMETER_ONE",
        "PARAMETER_TWO"
})
public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
    return new SomeObject();
}
```

I would like them to display like this when auto-reformatting code

```
@SomeCustomAnnotation({"PARAMETER_ONE", "PARAMETER_TWO"})
public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
    return new SomeObject();
}
```

I cannot seem to find the correct code style setting for this. Please assist

Comment: @CrazyCoder Are you saying it is not something currently supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Control + Alt + S) -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces.

Near the bottom under Annotation parameters, it probably says "Wrap if long". Change that to "Do not wrap" if you want it to be on a single line.

**Edit:**

The correct code-style to modify is `Array initializer`. Change that from `Wrap if long` to `Do not wrap`. That should work.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. I works for @Annotation3(param1 = "value1", param2 = "value2") but not for the way I have it specified

Comment: Yes sorry, I misread the sample code the first time. I've edited the answer with the correct solution.